# Azure Data Factory: time out on Time To First Byte, not full copy time

Tags: azure-data-factory

I would like to make an Azure Data factory copy task timeout on the "Time to first Byte" time, is this possible?

[image: Time to first byte]

As far as I can see there is only a total time out for the full copy step which when a job that takes a long time isn't that useful. Eg this big data set takes 1hr to download so have a few retries on it but if its not getting any data in the first 5minutes its ok to fail and try again.

When the only timeout on the full run of the copy job it spends an hour thirty just waiting then times out and tries again, when it could have tried again after 5 minutes or so, but I can't change the time out from 1hr30 because if it was copying successfully it would kill it in error

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no way to make any updates in the timeout in Azure Data factory copy task if no data is target end.

You can raise a feature request for that [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/1219ec2d-6c26-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c)

But as an alternative, you can update your pipeline with the logic that checks if the data has been received at the target system within the first 5 mins. If no data received at the target end within 5 mins, it will fail the pipeline.

This is my pipeline structure for your requirement:

[image]

Step 1: Configure your Copy activity to transfer the data from the source to target system.

Step 2: Use a Wait activity to make the pipeline wait for the desired time out period (in my case, I have taken as 1 min).
[image]

Step 3: Now use the Get Metadata Activity to take the size of the file in the target system. So our pipeline will wait for 1 min and then take the size of the file in the target system.
[image]

Step 4: Configure the IF Condition activity, we have taken the Size as argument and checked if the size of the target file is greater than 0 byte.

[image]

You can use the expression,

`@greater(activity('Check the size of the file').output.size, 0)`

[image]

Once the data is starts to get inserted in the target system, the pipeline will execute fine, otherwise it will go in the else statement and it will fail the pipeline as we are using the Fail Activity in else statement.

Comment: Interesting, does a fail task  work like that and stop other pipeline objects that are in progress ? i thought it was sort of on its own and so yes this will fail the pipeline, but it wont fail it early as it will still be in progress?

Comment: you can try this approach instead, you can create 2 pipelines. In pipeline1, we need to configure the copy pipeline with the source and sink details. In pipeline2, we can use the execute pipeline for pipeline1 and then use the same logic (using the wait activity to wait for the specified time, Get metadata activity for taking the size of the target file, and then if condition activity to check if the size of the target file is more than 0. If yes, nothing to perform. If not, then we can take the web activity and in the body, we can use the cancel pipeline1.

Comment: This will help us to cancel the pipeline after the specified amount of time if the data is not getting inserted into the target system.